# Best way to setup magento 2 on virtualbox as shared folder

Tags: magento2, server-setup, virtual

Being magento newby I ask for advice setting up `magento 2` on `virtualbox` as `shared folder`. I already have a setup but is impossible to work with because is causing loading gaps.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem only on Windows. On other OS you can use NFS for shared folder.

Best way do not use shared folder at all.  You need setup linux with X server and run PhpStorm from linux.

Also you can review recommended Vagrant file for magento  https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers